# Convert day names to abbreviation

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Consider that i have the day names as ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday", "Sunday"].

I need to get the abbreviated day_name as ["M", "T", "Th", "S", "Su"]

Is this possible to achieve using moment js?

Or how this can be done using javascript?

Comment: Just make a mapping lookup `abbreviations = { "Monday": "M", "Tuesday": "T", "Thursday": "Th", "Saturday": "S", "Sunday": "Su" }`?

Comment: Try using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) I think it has got a pattern like that in its `format` function

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible, check this out:

```js
// (1) moment.js
console.log(moment("2017-08-30T00:00:00").format('dd'));

const myDay = "Thursday";

// (2) array index
console.log(
  ["M", "T", "Th", "S", "Su"][[
    "Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
  ].indexOf(myDay)]
)

// (3) object
console.log({
  "Monday": "M", 
  "Tuesday": "T", 
  "Thursday": "Th", 
  "Saturday": "S", 
  "Sunday": "Su"
}[myDay])
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```